# XCOPY: Is it possible that the source folder contains the destination folder?

Tags: vba, windows, xcopy

I want to copy a folder with xcopy. However, as soon as I place the destination folder in the source folder, nothing is being copied anymore. Is there a workaround for this problem?

The idea is to generate a backup of an entire folder strucutre (source) into one subfolder. When executing xcopy I exclude the subfolder for the backup (destination), where my backups should be stored.

I have already tested my code and it works just fine as long as the destination folder does no lie within the source folder.

The code is written with VBA.

```
Function CopyFolder(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destinationPath As String, ByVal excludeFile As String)
    Dim wsh As Object
    Set wsh = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1

    ' /e -> copys all subfolders including empty ones; /k -> retains the read-only attribute if existend
    wsh.Run "xcopy " & sourcePath & " " & destinationPath & " /e /k /exclude:" & excludeFile, vbNormalFocus, waitOnReturn
End Function
```

The code is being executed with no error, but when I check the destination folder, no files haven been copied.

Answer (score 0):

this should not be possible since it should end with the error: "unable to execute a cyclic copy" or stuff like that.

if you want you can do something like this (one-liner):

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=;" %A IN (`dir %sourcePath% /B /AD ^|FINDSTR /V "%destinationPath%"`) DO @xcopy "%sourcePath%\%A\*.*" "%destinationPath%\" /EK
```

if the SOURCE is filled with directories that you should copy in the DEST. subdirectory with all their files.

Pay Attention to:

```
 ... %A IN (**`** .... **`**)   <---- theese are reverse quotes (alt+96)

... /AD **^**|FINDSTR /V        <---- this CAP has to be written explicitly like this (but without asterisks, obvious)

 %sourcePath% and %destinationPath%     <---  This is the batch variable notation. Do your String concatenation magic here, since you're launching from inside a vba
```

Hope this helps you! :-)

Bye